# Python Tkinter wireworld animation slowing down over time

Tags: python, performance, tkinter

Hi I'm programming a wireworld in python. I'm currently working on the animation\GUI and facing some problems. The animation slows down after a few seconds.
I'm fairly new to programming and very new to python and OOP so I'm open to advice and suggestions, but my specific problem here is that I can't figure out what's so wrong with my code that it takes 50 percent CPU to display little squares changing color...

So it would be great if someone could help me on this.

Here is my code:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import random as rd


class Universe(object):
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.cells = dict()
        for i in range(0, height):
            for j in range(0, width):
                self.cells[(i, j)] = Cell((i, j), 0, width, height)

    def generate_random(self):
        for current_cell in self.cells:
            self.cells[current_cell].state = rd.randint(0, 3)

    def apply_rules(self):
        next_state = dict()
        for current_cell in self.cells:
            if self.cells[current_cell].state == 3:
                if self.cells[current_cell].count_electron_heads(self) == 1:
                    next_state[current_cell] = 1
                elif self.cells[current_cell].count_electron_heads(self) == 2:
                    next_state[current_cell] = 1
                else:
                    next_state[current_cell] = 3
            elif self.cells[current_cell].state == 2:
                next_state[current_cell] = 3
            elif self.cells[current_cell].state == 1:
                next_state[current_cell] = 2
            else:
                next_state[current_cell] = 0

        for current_cell in next_state:
            self.cells[current_cell].state = next_state[current_cell]

    def plain_text_display(self):
        for i in range(0, self.height):
            row = list()
            for j in range(0, self.width):
                row.append(self.cells[(i, j)].state)
            print(row)


class Cell(object):
    def __init__(self, coordinates, state, universe_width, universe_height):
        self.state = state
        self.coordinates = coordinates
        self.neighborhood = [[self.coordinates[0] - 1, self.coordinates[1] - 1],
                             [self.coordinates[0] - 1, self.coordinates[1]],
                             [self.coordinates[0] - 1, self.coordinates[1] + 1],
                             [self.coordinates[0], self.coordinates[1] - 1],
                             [self.coordinates[0], self.coordinates[1] + 1],
                             [self.coordinates[0] + 1, self.coordinates[1] - 1],
                             [self.coordinates[0] + 1, self.coordinates[1]],
                             [self.coordinates[0] + 1, self.coordinates[1] + 1]]

        for i in range(0, len(self.neighborhood)):
            if self.neighborhood[i][0] < 0:
                self.neighborhood[i][0] = universe_height - 1
            elif self.neighborhood[i][0] > universe_height - 1:
                self.neighborhood[i][0] = 0
            if self.neighborhood[i][1] < 0:
                self.neighborhood[i][1] = universe_width - 1
            elif self.neighborhood[i][1] > universe_width - 1:
                self.neighborhood[i][1] = 0

    def count_electron_heads(self, universe):
        electron_heads_count = 0
        for neighbor_cell_coordinates in self.neighborhood:
            if universe.cells[(neighbor_cell_coordinates[0], neighbor_cell_coordinates[1])].state == 1:
                electron_heads_count += 1
        return electron_heads_count


class GUI(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, universe):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.cell_size = 12
        self.ui_frame = tk.Frame(self, width=self.cell_size*universe.width, height=60, bg="#282729")
        self.ui_frame.pack(fill="x", expand=True)
        self.cell_canvas = tk.Canvas(self, width=self.cell_size*universe.width, height=self.cell_size*universe.height,
                                     borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)
        self.cell_canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        self.cells = dict()
        for i in range(0, universe.height):
            for j in range(0, universe.width):
                if universe.cells[(i, j)].state == 1:
                    color = "#0099FF"
                elif universe.cells[(i, j)].state == 2:
                    color = "#CCFFFF"
                elif universe.cells[(i, j)].state == 3:
                    color = "#EDBE02"
                else:
                    color = "#0C1010"
                self.cells[(i, j)] = self.cell_canvas.create_rectangle(j*self.cell_size, i*self.cell_size,
                                                                       (j+1)*self.cell_size, (i+1)*self.cell_size,
                                                                       fill=color, tag=universe.cells[(i, j)])
        self.draw_button = tk.Button(self.ui_frame, text="Draw", command=lambda: self.draw(universe))
        self.draw_button.pack(side="left")

    def draw(self, universe):
        for i in range(0, universe.height):
            for j in range(0, universe.width):
                if universe.cells[(i, j)].state == 1:
                    color = "#0099FF"
                elif universe.cells[(i, j)].state == 2:
                    color = "#CCFFFF"
                elif universe.cells[(i, j)].state == 3:
                    color = "#EDBE02"
                else:
                    color = "#0C1010"
                self.cells[(i, j)] = self.cell_canvas.create_rectangle(j*self.cell_size, i*self.cell_size,
                                                                       (j+1)*self.cell_size, (i+1)*self.cell_size,
                                                                       fill=color, tag=universe.cells[(i, j)])
        universe.apply_rules()
        self.after(200, lambda: self.draw(universe))




wireworld = Universe(20, 20)
wireworld.generate_random()
g = GUI(wireworld)

g.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, every 200 milliseconds you are creating new 400 rectangles on a canvas. After just 10 seconds you have 20,000 rectangles. Once you start getting into the tens of thousands of objects, the canvas will start to slow down. Once you have over a couple hundred thousand it will start to get really slugging. You'll have made 100,000 objects in less than a minute.

You need to adjust your algorithm to create all of the rectangles just once. After that you only need to adjust their color using the `itemconfig` method. Assuming you only want to change the color with each frame of animation,  in the method `draw` replace the code where you are creating the rectangle with this:

```
self.cell_canvas.itemconfig(self.cells[(i,j)], fill=color)
```